# Excel/Google Sheets: Append every nth column in range to another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I'd like to be able to

- specify columns by saying "Starting on column D, I want every third column"
- make these show up in one "total" column

The image probably describes it a little better - instead of doing `={Range1; Range2; Range 3; ...}` manually for each desired range, a formula to do what I have described would make more sense.

[image]

In the example there are two axis but I don't mind having to +1 the formula for the other column, my main concern is the "selecting every nth and adding up" part

Comment: How many of these boxes that need to be combined do you have and have all of them the same length?

Comment: Hey @carl, currently 5 boxes, they are all between 10 and 14 entries in rows, with some rows being completely empty but I don't mind if the empty ones showed up in the final list

Comment: "make these show up in one "total" column "... where is the total column?  |  one more.. which one is column D? (the column header is not captured in the screenshot.)

Comment: @p._phidot_ column D is the first one that has "Date" mentioned. If we go 3 columns to the right, we always hit another column. The "total" column will eventually be on another sheet but for layout reasons on the picture I put it below the `->` mark (the big bottommost rectangle). I want to add up every third column in a range and then have these displayed somewhere else.

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are very different. Please specify one or the other for your question. Questions about Sheets are also not on topic here, but should be asked on the Web Apps sister site.

Comment: @user2875404,    ... one that has "Date" mentioned <-- and the row number = ?  (the row header is not captured in the screenshot.)

Answer (score 1):

The biggest complication in your example comes from the situation that the cells are not adjacent and you have two dimensions, otherwise it would be very easy to solve this problem. However, I think a very simple VBA solution should work. This code makes the following assumptions: The worksheet is called "Sheet1", the totals are collected in columns A and B respectively, your data starts in column D and must always be increased by 3 columns accordingly.

In the first part of the code, the last column with values is identified, thus you do not have to worry about adjusting anything whether you have 5 or 50 cases. It also initializes the number of total rows, which is needed to store the output. Proceeding in this way is advantageous, because also cases can be covered where, for example, the last two values of Fails are empty but Dates are present and vice versa. In the next step, the code loops through each column starting with i = 4 (column D) to the last column - 1 (because the point of reference is the Date column) in steps of 3, computes the number of rows as the max of Dates and Fails, collects the respective information and copies it to columns A (1) and B (2) respectively and finally updates the number of total rows, which is required to copy each set of new cases below the already existing cases.

This approach will of course work equally well for situations where the row numbers vary across cases. If you want the results to be stored on a different sheet, this approach can easily be extended to always shift the sheet before inserting the information, but since you have indicated that your data starts in column D, I think one can assume that the totals are in columns A and B, respectively.

```
Sub Stack_Columns()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, lastColumn, lastRow, totalRow As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastColumn = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
totalRow = 1
    
    For i = 4 To lastColumn - 1 Step 3
        lastRow = Application.Max(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row, ws.Cells(Rows.Count, i + 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i), ws.Cells(lastRow, i)).Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(totalRow + 1, "A")
        ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, i + 1), ws.Cells(lastRow, i + 1)).Copy Destination:=ws.Cells(totalRow + 1, "B")
        totalRow = totalRow + lastRow - 1
    Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```